# Unsure why a similar table is not using an Index

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

The preceding question has to be quite generic, as I can't include the Database/Column names as they actually are.

I have two tables; `table1` and `table2`. Both of these tables have the same index; `DATE_CUSTOMER` which is made up of the `DATE` field and the `Customer_Name` field.

`table1` has `24,127,915` rows and `table2` has `30,821,313` rows.

The query:

```
   EXPLAIN
   SELECT
     Customer,
     Server,
     WEEKDAY(DATE),
     HOUR(DATE),
     AVG(CPU)
   FROM
     table1/table2
   WHERE
     DATE >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND
     DATE < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   GROUP BY
     Customer,
     Server,
     WEEKDAY(DATE),
     HOUR(DATE)
```

The response from `table1`:

```
* id: 1
* select_type: SIMPLE
* table: table1
* type: range
* possible_keys: DATE_CUSTOMER
* key: DATE_CUSTOMER
* key_len: 8
* ref: (NULL)
* rows: 856,782
* Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

The response from `table2`:

```
* id: 1
* select_type: SIMPLE
* table: table2
* type: ALL
* possible_keys: DATE_CUSTOMER
* key: (NULL)
* key_len: (NULL)
* ref: (NULL)
* rows: 27,958,213
* Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

There are obvious differences between the two `EXPLAINS` but I'm unsure why one would use the index, be `range` etc, and the other not use the index and be `ALL`

**Edit** Just to add I have tried `Forcing` the Index (`FORCE INDEX (DATE_CUSTOMER)`) which obviously picks the index up in the `EXPLAIN` but the query run time is exactly the same (>9 minutes).

Comment: MySQL won't use the index if it won't help reduce number of rows it has to scan. Your table 2 returns ~28 million out of ~31 million total. That means a lot of records satisfy the `WHERE` clause. Index is useless here, it doesn't help MySQL to scan the data any less. Using an index is probably going to incur a performance penalty because it has to read the index, which doesn't help it at all, and then read the data.  You forced the index and you noticed that execution time stayed the same. Also, it definitely takes a huge amount of time to find / read / buffer / send so many rows.

Comment: @RickJames the `~` in mathematics means *approximately* equal, or if you will- *estimate*. I used that symbol. I also never stated that `EXPLAIN` estimates number of rows to **return**, so I've absolutely no clue why you're even highlighting me.

Comment: I quibble with "returns ~28M out of ~31M":  "type: ALL" and "key: (NULL)" say that the _entire_ table will be _scanned_, not just ~28/~31.  And no number in the table2 `EXPLAIN` even estimates how many rows will be _returned_.

Answer (score -1):

How many rows are *in that range*?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- we need to see various things, including what `INDEX date_customer (...)` says and what datatype `DATE` is.  This might also help in explaining `Using index condition`, which does not make sense based on what you have shown us.

This is the optimal index for those queries:

```
INDEX(date)
```

Back to the question.  (Pending answers for my questions, I will make some guesses.)

If the index can filter the number of rows down to less than (about) 20% of a table, then the index will be used.  This will involve bouncing between the index BTree and the Data BTree.  For table1, apparently the number is 3%.

Otherwise, the Optimizer decides that it is faster to ignore the index and simply scan the data.  We can't see what the % is for table2.

Another guess is that the "statistics" are messed up.  This is unlikely, especially in newer versions.  But, you could do `ANALYZE TABLE table2;` to see if that "fixes" the "problem".